# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module not supported in node_modules

Tags: typescript, commonjs, esmodules

I'm creating my web program with next.js. After upgraded node version, this error occured.

[image]

`Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module` ~ from ~ not supported.
This error happens my node_modules file.

I tried change the code require() -> import and added package.json "type" : "modules".
The problem is that the node_modules file has a cascade of errors. (Because it includes a lots of require() code)
Is there an efficient way to solve this problem?

Thank you for reading the English sentence even though it is not enough